# Fastest way to process a python list of tuples

Tags: python, django

In a Django project, I have a python list of tuples like so:

```
users_and_values = [(user_id,value),(user_id,value),......]
```

where `value` can either be 0.0 or 1.0 (float). Given this list, I need to create a new one, which is like so:

```
[(user_object,value),(user_object,value),......]
```

where `user_object` is the object associated with each `user_id` (containing user attributes and such).

**What is the most efficient way to achieve this (performance and correctness both matter)?** Currently, I'm trying to achieve that as follows in a Django view:

```
    user_ids = [user_id for user_id, value in users_and_values]
    user_objs = User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids)
    context["votes"] = [(user_objs(user_id),value) for user_id, value in users_and_votes]
```

This gives me the error:

> 'QuerySet' object is not callable

I could also have tried `[(User.object.get(id=user_id),value) for user_id, value in users_and_values]`, but that would be too many DB calls. So can anyone chime in with what I'm doing wrong, and the correct solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user_objs` is an unordered collection of users. You have to manually map the user ids to the corresponding values by iterating over it:

```
user_ids = [user_id for user_id, value in users_and_values]
user_objs = User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids)

ids_to_values = dict(users_and_values)  # {id1: value1, ...}
context["votes"] = [(user, ids_to_values[user.id]) for user in user_objs]
```